# Debug an issue in an underlying C++ DLL

Tags: c#, c++, debugging, dll

I have a main application (in C#), which parses an image database, and then pipes those images into a C++ DLL to have them analysed. Now for some reason every 200 images or so, it throws an error. It doesn't always throw the error at the same image, but just at a random image (sometimes an image passes though the analysis, the other time it throws an error).

Can I somehow make my DLL throw an exception to the C# GUI with information on where in the C++ code the error originates from? The code itself should run fine, and I cannot find where the error is coming from, so I need some help from the DLL to identify at least where it happens.

Any help would be appreciated, I found nothing on that so far.

Comment: Do you have access to the source of the DLL? If not, then no.

Comment: Or, at least, the symbol files.  Try capturing a dump and running it through WinDbg

Comment: Could you enable disassembly viewing in Visual Studio to enable you to debug the C++ DLL when the error occurs?

Comment: I have access to everything, its my DLL. I ran the code in loop for 350 iterations with a failing image, yet it did not error out.

Comment: @MartinParkin I only see the error when the exception is caught from the GUI, I don't know when it will happen

Comment: @AntonRoth if you look at Hans Passant answer below, he is telling you how to enable debugging of the C++ DLL from your code.  This is what I was alluding to.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the debugger to diagnose this.  Enable the unmanaged debugger with Project + Properties, Debug tab, tick the "Enable unmanaged code debugging" option.

"it throws an error" is too vague to give specific advice.  But you'll want to check the Thrown checkbox in the Debug + Exceptions dialog.  Tick "C++ exceptions" and/or "Win32 exception", depending on the type of exception that's being thrown.  If you don't know then tick all of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to get the error when debugging it, in your C++ dll write to output the function that you are in.

For instance, if you have func1, func2, func3 in the dll then write out their names every time you enter and exit each function. When you run the program you will be able to narrow it to the function that is causing the exception, then you can add similar outputs after each line in the function to find the code that is throwing the exception.